# How or when to use cross-validation (model selection, parameter tuning,..)

Tags: cross-validation

I know there are many questions about cross validation but I couldn't find that generally describes all aspects (I have in my mind).
In [How to evaluate the final model after k-fold cross-validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161491/how-to-evaluate-the-final-model-after-k-fold-cross-validation) it is described that cross validation is used to select the best model.
I wonder about the following:

1. Why are different models not just trained on the same data set and tested on the same separated dataset? Why the effort for using a different data set for each model?
2. The same applies when searching the best parameters for a single model (like in grid search).

Can you please clear my questions?

[image: CV]

Comment: In my opinion, train/test approach gives you a point estimation which may be terribly wrong due to chance, but cross-validation is giving a distribution. Which is always better.

Comment: Thank you. But how exactly is it used?

Comment: Well, you select the fold-size according to your sample size, run cross-validation, look at the distribution of test performance and make conclusions =) like, how stable is the performance, what is the expected performance, etc. I think there are plenty of manuals on this.

Comment: *Why are different models not just trained on the same data set and tested on the same separated dataset? Why the effort for using a different data set for each model?* - I think you might be wrong here. Practitioners do train different models on the same data set and compare their performances . That's the approach when you want to select the best model for the given data.

Comment: @GermanDemidov CV also returns point estimates, which may be even "wronger", since they are estimated on less data. Would you rather have 5 estimates of the mean from 5 smaller samples or 1 estimate from a larger sample? OP: what naive said, different models are built on the same data and tested on the same data.

Comment: @user2974951 I can perform leave-one-out cross validation if my sample size is small. CV returns *number of folds* measures of performance - isn't it different from point estimate? Like, when we do bootstrap, is it point estimate what we get in the end? I think no, and I do not see a fundamental difference between CV and bootstrap in this sense. Like, this plot http://www.milanor.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/articolo_milanor_3.png clearly has confidence intervals.

Answer (score 2):

Writing an answer as answering in the comments is [not really desirable.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2642/168306)

> Why are different models not just trained on the same data set and tested on the same separated dataset? Why the effort for using a different data set for each model?

- I think you might be wrong here. Practitioners do train different models on the same data set and compare their performances . That's the approach when you want to select the best model for the given data.

> How to perform cross-validation?

Have a look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373314/in-sample-data-vs-out-of-sample-data/373321#373321).